# Criteria API join clause with and operator

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I am trying to write a query involving the and operator with a join clause, as follows:

```
 Select distinct
product.id_product, 
Brand.value as 'brand',
FROM product
INNER JOIN [product_attribut] as BRAND on BRAND.id_product= product.id_product and BRAND.id_attribut = '1'
```

I don't know how to implement it with criteria API:

```
final CriteriaBuilder productCriteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = productCriteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object.class);
final Root<Product> root = criteriaQuery.from(Product.class);
final Join<Product, ProductAttribut> productBrand= root.join("productAttributs");
    Predicate brandPredicate = productCriteriaBuilder.and(productBrand, productCriteriaBuilder.equal(productBrand.get("id_attribut"), "1"));
```

But the and() method should take objects of type Expression.
Is there any workaround for this ? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have a single predicate, so using `and` is useless. All you need is criteriaQuery.where(theOnlyPredicateYouHave). Why don't yourespect the Java naming conventions?